# Magento 2 API - crud for all tables

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, crud

Is it possible to create a new REST API to update or create data in all magento tables from a xml added in POST :

```
<data>
    <row table="Nom_Table_1" key="Nom_Champ_Key_1">
        <column name="Nom_Champ1" type="string">value1</column>
        <column name="Nom_Champ2" type="integer">5</column>
        <column name="Nom_Champ3" type="double">21.5</column>
        <column name="Nom_Champ4" type="date_time">2018-09-24T15:22:27.000+02:00</column>
    </row>
    <row table="Nom_Table_2" key="Nom_Champ_Key_2">
        <column name="Nom_Champ1" type="string">value1</column>
        <column name="Nom_Champ2" type="integer">7</column>
    </row>
</data>
```